# d3 rollup split string into multiple

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hei,
I have data that looks like this:

```
Datum,Name,Kategorie,Betrag
01/10/15,,Lohn,1586,7
02/10/15,,lunch,-4,55
....
...
..
.
```

Now I'm trying to put I've put it into a d3 rollup like this:

```
d3.csv("mein-budget-export.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  var summedData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {  
      //console.log(d.Datum);
      return d.Datum;
    })
    .rollup(function(v) { return {
        total: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.Betrag; }),
        category: v.map(function(d){
            return d.Kategorie;
          }), 
      }; 
    })
    .entries(data);
```

Working nicely. Now what I'm trying to do is to have in the rollup a separate value for day, month and year (as ints), which means that in the rollup I want to access the "Datum" field again, but I cannot do it. I've tried multiple things one was like this

```
day: function(d){return parseInt(d.Datum.substring(0, 2));}
```

When I look in the inspector inside the values I get `day: function(d)` instead of e.g., 15
probably this is easy but I'm new to d3 so I don't quite get it yet...
thanks in advance for help!

---

EDIT: 
apparently the main problem is in how to access the values directly inside the rollup. just `d.Datum` does not work as d is not defined. `v.Datum` is also undefined. so what's the way to access Datum directly inside the rollup. I cannot find any example online...

Comment: There is no need to wrap that into a function of its own. Have you tried `day: parseInt(d.Datum.substring(0, 2))`?

Comment: @altocumulus yes that gives me an error "d is not defined" and if I use v it gives me an "cannot read property of undefined" then the basic question is how do I access Datum inside here?

Comment: Ah, of course, try `day: parseInt(v[0].Datum.substring(0, 2))` instead.

Comment: yes I just figured that through more trial and error myself. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: There is another issue with your CSV: the way it is now, your `Betrag` values rely on the comma as the decimal mark, which also acts as the separator for *C*SV data. You will loose your fractional part of `Betrag` because the comma causes this to be interpreted as an additional column in the data, which doesn't match any column in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to wrap the code in a function. Because the function is never called, it will bind the reference to the function to `day` which is the result you have seen while inspecting the output. Your `rollup()` function should look like this:

```
.rollup(function(v) { 
    var datum = v[0].Datum;
    return {
        day: parseInt(datum.substr(0, 2)),
        month: parseInt(datum.substr(3, 2)),
        year: parseInt(datum.substr(6, 2)),
        total: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.Betrag; }),
        category: v.map(function(d) { return d.Kategorie; }), 
    }; 
})
```